# Rest, coredata and server side filtering

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I'm developing an application on iOS that consumes a (mostly) RESTful service. I'm supposed 
to display those posts with different filters, which are applied server side :

- http://foo.com/posts?filter=recent
- http://foo.com/posts?filter=popular
- http://foo.com/posts?filter=special
- ...

I'm contemplating using Restkit (0.20) to do all this properly, using the coredata module for caching and I have a little poc running.

My question is, how can I then query core-data to fetch my entities back, using those same filters locally? I could add a special field to "tag" the posts and then filter on that, but I don't know how I could do that with RestKit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you save the posts locally, I am assuming that you are creating some entities. You would need to create another entity called filter and have a many to many relationship between posts and filters. So if the user selects a filter you will know all the posts he wants to read. Just create the two entities and set up a relationship on either side for filter. You will need to either prepopulate filters entity or populate it as you do your Rest requests, at which time yo will know the filter names

Comment: RestKit handles the entity caching for me. What you said makes sense though, so I'll have to see if this works for me in practice, or if I'll have to ditch RestKit.
Thanks for the tip
(I'll update this question when/if I get something satisfying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution :

- I've added some properties to my Entity
- I subclassed RKManagedObjectRequestOperation to populate those properties
- I subclassed RKObjectManager to return my custom RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.

More details at [the official Restkit google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/restkit/iDAUqKl55Ys)

Cheers